# Bootstrap Responsive Site Ingores Viewport Setting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, viewport

Why does our responsive site, in a 320px wide window, scale differently on a phone, than it does on a desktop browser

The **problem** turned out to be this update in Bootstrap's v2.3.2 responsive-utilities.less file.

```
@-ms-viewport{
  /* comment this out!!! */
  width: device-width;
}
```

When we commented this out, the mobile 320px browser renders the same as a desktop 320px browser does.

We did not have to make any other changes. That is, it was okay to have 1500px images in our site, and we didn't have to change our existing viewport meta tag, which is as follows:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

A follow up question: what is that @-ms-viewport line for anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Add a 100% width on the offending image in your CSS, that should clear up any issues.

EDIT:

The ms-viewport tag in your css is actually the standard way according to the W3 spec to implement a viewport tag. [Trent Walton](http://trentwalton.com/2013/01/16/windows-phone-8-viewport-fix/) has a great [post](http://trentwalton.com/2013/01/16/windows-phone-8-viewport-fix/) and links to a [few more](http://timkadlec.com/2012/10/ie10-snap-mode-and-responsive-design/) that explain the rule.

I'm not sure why that rule is causing a problem, I've used it in combination with several sites and never had an issue.

Comment: Good idea but we did not need to do that in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. That turned out not to be necessary, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can setting full propeties as bellow :)

```
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=1" name="viewport" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem you should check if you can adjust it in the css or stop the responsive script for some components.

Don't choose the ready one "stop bootstrap responsive script" in google it won't work well it will mess up your navbar responsiveness.